# Derived Class Member Initialization by base class constructor

Tags: c++

I have one doubt regarding this code that this code is not correct. it can crash at run time.As **p** pointer is pointing to address of **derived** class member variable(char array)
but before derived class constructor **base** class constructor gets called so memory initialization and allocation for derived class is not yet done. So when in base class constructor we do **strcpy** this code might crash.

```
class Base
{
 public: 
  char *p;
  Base(){};
  Base(char *a):p(a)
  {
     sprintf(a,"HELLO");
  };
};
class Derived:public Base
{
 public:
 char arr[10];
 Derived():Base(arr)
 {

 };

};

int main()
{
   Derived d = new Derived();
return 0;
}
```

From This code what i intend to do is to give address of char array to base class where some string needs to be written on address passed.
But i am not sure this code will work always.
Please clarify.

Comment: Your doubts are eligible. Just passing the pointer in the constructor is harmless, using it there with `sprintf` isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well-defined, but fragile - it can break if you change the type of `arr`.

Storage is allocated for the complete object before running any constructor and, since `arr` has trivial initialisation, its lifetime begins as soon as storage has been allocated. It's therefore usable in the `Base` constructor.

If it were a non-trivial type, like `std::string`, then it wouldn't be usable in the `Base` constructor, and you'd have undefined behaviour.

Comment: This behaviour is standard or can vary according to compiler ?

Comment: @anshulgarg: It's standard. Object lifetimes are specified in C++11 3.8, if you want the gory details.